# Telerik Winforms Radgridview display joined information in dropdown

Tags: sql-server, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have two tables in MSSQL

Customers:
kID
customername

Projects:
pid
projectname
kID

Now I have a Radgridview for the Projects and I want to show the customername instead of the kID and if someone enters editmode for the kid-column I want to have a dropdown with customernames(but the id as value) to show.

How do I do this with Radgridview?
I couldn't find a solution, but I guess that's a very common task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [GridViewComboBoxColumn](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/columns/column-types/gridviewcomboboxcolumn) for the purpose. On the provided page you can see how to set it up.

Comment: How do I have to create the Dataset for this? You can't join the Tables in there...

Comment: Ok, Couldn't find out how to make this at design time, but programatically it works like described in the Link you provided.

Comment: At design time, you can access the Property Builder from the control Smart Tag and work your way out.